# Numerical integration of this trigonometric function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-calculus

$$  \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(10^6\sin(\pi \cdot 10^2 \sqrt{10 y^2 + 10}))}{\sin(\pi \cdot 10^2 \sqrt{10 y^2 + 10})}dy  $$

What sort of numerical integration method works for this kind of problem? Guassian Quadrature, trapezoidal?

I'm not so good with numerical integrals of this type sorry and even WolframAlpha has a problem finding the integral.

Comment: @Moo yeah I did

Comment: @Moo thanks I'm a noob at this sort of integrals like I said.

Comment: Since the integrand is from $0$ to $1$, I would just use the series expansion for $\sin(x)$ and since it's odd, the denominator will cancel.

Comment: @DecarbonatedOdes how would you handle the 10^6 constant won't that make the Taylor series require more terms?

Comment: Any numerical integration would "work." It's just a matter of how close you want to get to the actual value of the integral, how many rectangles you want to use, and what approximation technique you prefer.